# AC-powered electromagnets: does one end repel?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

Using AC to power two electromagnets from the same source, when putting the two magnets together, does one end attract and the other repel (because the phase is exactly 180°)? a similar behaviour to DC.

Comment: Relative to each other, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The North and South poles of the magnets will cycle back and forth with the AC cycle. With the same power supply the magnets poles will cycle at the same rate so they will attract or repel each other similar to DC powered electromagnets.